# What are the factors i should consider to select any MVC Framework

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have worked on struts 1.2 and DWR as front end MVC framework.Now i have two projects to develop one is simple web application and another is complex.**Which one i should  select from most prevalent MVC Framework  Spring mvc, Struts 2, DWR,JSF and brief reason to select any of the MVC** . Most of the team knows all the frameworks. **What are the factors i should consider to select any Framework.**

Comment: This is worth a read http://olex.openlogic.com/wazi/2010/choosing-the-right-java-web-development-framework/

Comment: I would consider what is the scope of my project, if I am anticipating complex system with lots and lots of various implementations, then I would go for Spring, for moderately complex system I would go for JSF. One also need to consider if the primary designer leaves the team will other team members or a new comer will be able to pick particular MVC framework with ease or not (consider using well known MVV vs not-so-well known). How mature the particular MVC framework is, are there good books written about it etc. These are just from top of my head.

Comment: @UsmanSaleem, I think you can post it as an answer, not as a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would consider what is the scope of my project, if I am anticipating complex system with lots and lots of various implementations, then I would go for Spring, for moderately complex system I would go for JSF.

One also need to consider if the primary designer leaves the team would other team members or a new comer will be able to pick particular MVC framework with ease or not (consider using well known MVC vs not-so-well-known-personal-favourite-picked-out-of-google). How mature the particular MVC framework is, are there good books written about it etc. These are just from top of my head.

Also keep in mind when there is too much of Spring (or any other ioC container) involved, there comes a time (after 8-12 months) when you are unable to debug code correctly because there are so many classes involved that you just keep tracking which class goes to which spring context files etc.

Finally, as one of my mentors used to say, don't solve the world problems (by using lots of  design patterns), solve the problem at hand. :-)